# Strange StrokeDashArray behavior on LineGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following style for a control which derives from a Shape type:

```
<Style
    x:Key="NavigationToolsStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationTool}"
    >
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="3 2"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Geometry">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <LineGeometry
                    StartPoint="0,0"
                    EndPoint="0,-12000"
                    />
                <LineGeometry
                    StartPoint="-35,0"
                    EndPoint="35,0"
                    />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Everything looks fine except for the shorter horizontal line:

[Why does the left side of the line looks like it is missing a 'dash gap'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvNlr.png)

EDIT:

Okay, removing the vertical line fixes the issue. But does anyone know why does it behave that way? And how to fix it to have those two lines together anyway?

EDIT2:

Indeed, changing the order in xaml fixes the issue.

Comment: Tried with a Path, and it behaves the same. A workaround is to change the order of the LineGeometries.

Comment: If "*two lines together*" is supposed to mean a single Geometry, use a PathGeometry like `<Setter Property="Geometry" Value="M-35,0 H35 M0,0 V-12000"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of the line geometries in xaml fixes the issue.